# Выборка по ключу из словаря

Tags: python, json, requests, dict

Есть паблик API, который выдает словарь при запросе на URL ([пример](https://tik.fail/api/tiktok/v1/hashtag/mom)). Он берет переменную после `hashtag/` и ищет видео по этому хештегу, после чего возвращает массив данных о полученных видео.

Мне нужно, чтобы мой код циклом отправлял оттуда ссылки на просмотр этих видео (ссылки на видео находятся в переменной `videoUrl`). У меня есть заготовка кода но она не работает. Использую библиотеку telethon ибо работаю с модулем telegram.

Kод:

```
args = utils.get_args_raw(event)
    reply = await event.get_reply_message()#Эта строка принимает введенные аргументы
    if not args:
        if not reply:
            await event.edit("где хештег.") #проверки на наличие аргумента
            return
        else:
            args = reply.raw_text
    response = requests.get('https://tik.fail/api/tiktok/v1/hashtag/' + args).json() #Тут мой запрос на api
    for dict_ in response["collector"]: #мой цикл который не работает
        await event.respond(dict_["videoUrl"]) #Это отправка сообщения
```

Comment: ладно, а можно понять что это дает а что отнимает

Answer (score 6, accepted):

воспользуйтесь модулем [dpath](https://pypi.org/project/dpath/):

```
import dpath.util as dpu

r = requests.get("https://tik.fail/api/tiktok/v1/hashtag/mom")
data = r.json()
res = dpu.values(data, "/**/videoUrl")
```

результат:

```
In [368]: res
Out[368]: 
['https://v16-web.tiktok.com/video/tos/useast2a/tos-useast2a-ve-0068c004/df4e76b7f28f4373a8fd164356bf76a5/?a=1988&br=2392&bt=1196&cr=0&cs=0&cv=1&dr=0&ds=3&er=&expire=1605137423&l=2020111117301001019018602943028554&lr=tiktok_m&mime_type=video_mp4&policy=2&qs=0&rc=M3R1NDNrb250czMzNDczM0ApZzszODtlZGQ5Nzc1M2hkNWcxaXJtcHFkbjFfLS0yMTZzczBhMzVhXmAwLTYyY2ItNTY6Yw%3D%3D&signature=f27621eac3f64ebb44dc23a1c4a122c8&tk=tt_webid_v2&vl=&vr=',
 'https://v16-web.tiktok.com/video/tos/useast2a/tos-useast2a-pve-0068/cde3d8c06d91412da54704c90d600ae4/?a=1988&br=2214&bt=1107&cr=0&cs=0&cv=1&dr=0&ds=3&er=&expire=1605137430&l=2020111117301001019018602943028554&lr=tiktok_m&mime_type=video_mp4&policy=2&qs=0&rc=Mzdycnk1cG9rdzMzZjczM0ApN2Y8ZTU1OjxnNzpkNzk0ZGdvZDVgYzMvYHJfLS1iMTZzczAxYDIyMDQzMC01NGE2YDM6Yw%3D%3D&signature=ac819ee31f59d0b05458dd7ef005d7aa&tk=tt_webid_v2&vl=&vr=',
 'https://v16-web.tiktok.com/video/tos/useast2a/tos-useast2a-ve-0068c003/9105dfb5880e4bb4a17dcd8d3f2c8579/?a=1988&br=3240&bt=1620&cr=0&cs=0&cv=1&dr=0&ds=3&er=&expire=1605137450&l=2020111117301001019018602943028554&lr=tiktok_m&mime_type=video_mp4&policy=2&qs=0&rc=Mzo7bHZsdG05eDMzPDczM0ApNTg3ZGRoZDxoNzs4OWc6Z2dzbjZvbzA0ZzZfLS1iMTZzczUyMWAuM2A0YjFgYDZgMS06Yw%3D%3D&signature=07b24e934947a36d8d8be2332c3e8d50&tk=tt_webid_v2&vl=&vr=',
 'https://v16-web.tiktok.com/video/tos/useast2a/tos-useast2a-ve-0068c004/aec63ad3e1c34ed1b29dcb0da681709e/?a=1988&br=858&bt=429&cr=0&cs=0&cv=1&dr=0&ds=3&er=&expire=1605137417&l=2020111117301001019018602943028554&lr=tiktok_m&mime_type=video_mp4&policy=2&qs=0&rc=amU0aXB2cWk5czMzNDczM0ApOjNkOjYzNTs3NzZlaWlmNWc2Ml5pajMwY2JfLS01MTZzc2JhNjFeXi5jYi5eY2FgMTY6Yw%3D%3D&signature=2580301fb00329cb356297c3ae7051a6&tk=tt_webid_v2&vl=&vr=',
 'https://v16-web.tiktok.com/video/tos/useast2a/tos-useast2a-ve-0068c003/e2140418949c46cc92557218cb02d900/?a=1988&br=1928&bt=964&cr=0&cs=0&cv=1&dr=0&ds=3&er=&expire=1605137422&l=2020111117301001019018602943028554&lr=tiktok_m&mime_type=video_mp4&policy=2&qs=0&rc=ajM4cGtnN2Z1czMzNjczM0ApOGY4Ozc2ODs7NzY8aDs4OGdhLTEwcWRrNV5fLS0zMTZzc19gYl9eMTIvMV8vNGJiLjQ6Yw%3D%3D&signature=7c71508d75401999f09a1885bbba9273&tk=tt_webid_v2&vl=&vr=',
 'https://v16-web.tiktok.com/video/tos/useast2a/tos-useast2a-pve-0068/2c5d8bf4bc834652ad903a69237818aa/?a=1988&br=3326&bt=1663&cr=0&cs=0&cv=1&dr=0&ds=3&er=&expire=1605137425&l=2020111117301001019018602943028554&lr=tiktok_m&mime_type=video_mp4&policy=2&qs=0&rc=M246aXBoaGpuczMzNDczM0ApMzc4OzNlZzw0Nzc6NWU7N2dpNC1sZzBtY2xfLS0tMTZzczJjXi0zLjExNjQ0M18tMC46Yw%3D%3D&signature=30f84676218e0cb8d068596ec684bb50&tk=tt_webid_v2&vl=&vr=',
 'https://v16-web.tiktok.com/video/tos/useast2a/tos-useast2a-ve-0068c002/b0f23b73e98f44718f74b2087c67f014/?a=1988&br=3526&bt=1763&cr=0&cs=0&cv=1&dr=0&ds=3&er=&expire=1605137421&l=2020111117301001019018602943028554&lr=tiktok_m&mime_type=video_mp4&policy=2&qs=0&rc=amdlbW5wNjVrdTMzOzczM0ApODg1MzxpZzs5NzRlNGZpOWdvLl5kZG9kNjRfLS1fMTZzc2FfMDMwMzIzYGJeX181YTA6Yw%3D%3D&signature=60d060903934092f0323b210c4265c8f&tk=tt_webid_v2&vl=&vr=',
 'https://v16-web.tiktok.com/video/tos/useast2a/tos-useast2a-ve-0068c001/1c5540c19dc143d6b740bb7d64897986/?a=1988&br=1518&bt=759&cr=0&cs=0&cv=1&dr=0&ds=3&er=&expire=1605137429&l=2020111117301001019018602943028554&lr=tiktok_m&mime_type=video_mp4&policy=2&qs=0&rc=anZ2ZnVnZHU6dDMzNjczM0ApOmQ2ZjVmMztkNzU8ZTxpZmdxbmkwbXAvcXBfLS01MTZzc2BjXmJfNDE0MC4zNDNeYGA6Yw%3D%3D&signature=fef9297bc39053416cfdbdcdf13b3d28&tk=tt_webid_v2&vl=&vr=',
 'https://v16-web.tiktok.com/video/tos/useast2a/tos-useast2a-pve-0068/5d1fd498485d4010a57e76ee4ce73922/?a=1988&br=2332&bt=1166&cr=0&cs=0&cv=1&dr=0&ds=3&er=&expire=1605137467&l=2020111117301001019018602943028554&lr=tiktok_m&mime_type=video_mp4&policy=2&qs=0&rc=M2VkN3huaDN1djMzZjczM0ApZGVlOmc8NWU3NzloMzNnNWcuYG8wMjNuM2RfLS0vMTZzczAtLy8wMC5iNjNhNjBiMzI6Yw%3D%3D&signature=2cdc700934e64371e2b1a2b5e3501bdf&tk=tt_webid_v2&vl=&vr=',
 'https://v16-web.tiktok.com/video/tos/useast2a/tos-useast2a-ve-0068c002/042edf726b134fa196c0c7f3d5b83eec/?a=1988&br=2698&bt=1349&cr=0&cs=0&cv=1&dr=0&ds=3&er=&expire=1605137464&l=2020111117301001019018602943028554&lr=tiktok_m&mime_type=video_mp4&policy=2&qs=0&rc=M286am13cm88eDMzOjczM0ApOzxoZWg4NTxoN2VpOTM4aGdmMG1eLi9fNGJfLS01MTZzczU1LjQuL18uYV5iYTIyMmE6Yw%3D%3D&signature=55dfddc4a5dc234293542f8854251093&tk=tt_webid_v2&vl=&vr=',
 'https://v16-web.tiktok.com/video/tos/useast2a/tos-useast2a-ve-0068c003/46b442d25a724a138e4f85cb401c2b30/?a=1988&br=2720&bt=1360&cr=0&cs=0&cv=1&dr=0&ds=3&er=&expire=1605137454&l=2020111117301001019018602943028554&lr=tiktok_m&mime_type=video_mp4&policy=2&qs=0&rc=amQ5bGY6bGk8dzMzNzczM0ApODlmPDM1aTxpNzNpMzk4O2dsM2twZ2liZi5fLS1eMTZzcy4wYmEvYmMzLjMxYDVhYzA6Yw%3D%3D&signature=dcac0cc867539894e448a0aaeb830458&tk=tt_webid_v2&vl=&vr=',
 'https://v16-web.tiktok.com/video/tos/useast2a/tos-useast2a-pve-0068/4c750e54256a4c5c96d66ad4272a5209/?a=1988&br=3326&bt=1663&cr=0&cs=0&cv=1&dr=0&ds=3&er=&expire=1605137440&l=2020111117301001019018602943028554&lr=tiktok_m&mime_type=video_mp4&policy=2&qs=0&rc=M3hud3V5eXhxdDMzaDczM0ApNTlmOTk8Mzw4NzkzZWdkZGdfcWxhMV9nX2lfLS0vMTZzczM0NTFhXi1iNWMzLWEuMDA6Yw%3D%3D&signature=5ac4a531a5832bb4f2f65f5968e2a4e7&tk=tt_webid_v2&vl=&vr=',
 'https://v16-web.tiktok.com/video/tos/useast2a/tos-useast2a-ve-0068/6afcd930ad514cd7b5b9fd2d4915b7f6/?a=1988&br=4430&bt=2215&cr=0&cs=0&cv=1&dr=0&ds=3&er=&expire=1605137430&l=2020111117301001019018602943028554&lr=tiktok_m&mime_type=video_mp4&policy=2&qs=0&rc=M2Q0eDx4N3BoczMzZjczM0ApNjw4aDQ5ZGRpNzo5OTU4OGdtczJvLTJgLS5fLS1eMTZzc2EvLy02YC8uMF5eLzAyMTQ6Yw%3D%3D&signature=6c7b660a16be38a1a036f3a0664c7d7d&tk=tt_webid_v2&vl=&vr=',
 'https://v16-web.tiktok.com/video/tos/useast2a/tos-useast2a-pve-0068/4a2204fc08a34d1489b80c1c7c72a4ba/?a=1988&br=3528&bt=1764&cr=0&cs=0&cv=1&dr=0&ds=3&er=&expire=1605137451&l=2020111117301001019018602943028554&lr=tiktok_m&mime_type=video_mp4&policy=2&qs=0&rc=amU8ZjhydmVsdDMzZDczM0ApOjY3Ozw8ODtlNzM7aGc6PGdpYmJyYWBrZGBfLS0uMTZzcy8xLTUyM2AxNTU2YV8xNTQ6Yw%3D%3D&signature=99e35498313d1c6e1729d2a7c7138512&tk=tt_webid_v2&vl=&vr=',
 'https://v16-web.tiktok.com/video/tos/alisg/tos-alisg-pve-0037c001/9c872b87d1634d2cad031845dbf35ef7/?a=1988&br=1654&bt=827&cr=0&cs=0&cv=1&dr=0&ds=3&er=&expire=1605137434&l=2020111117301001019018602943028554&lr=tiktok_m&mime_type=video_mp4&policy=2&qs=0&rc=amxzZDY7ZjlndzMzODczM0ApOzo8N2k6Zzs0Nzw3OztnNmdlMnJzX3FgZXNfLS1gMTRzc142MV4uM2FfLjMyMGJjLjU6Yw%3D%3D&signature=cfe598caf2b8c79e47f7ac9ab59ae85e&tk=tt_webid_v2&vl=&vr=',
 'https://v16-web.tiktok.com/video/tos/useast2a/tos-useast2a-pve-0068/b47659e2c0064934a54462fc73e71c10/?a=1988&br=2214&bt=1107&cr=0&cs=0&cv=1&dr=0&ds=3&er=&expire=1605137465&l=2020111117301001019018602943028554&lr=tiktok_m&mime_type=video_mp4&policy=2&qs=0&rc=MztrOHd0OXFydjMzMzczM0ApMzw8Omg4OzxoNzc3ZjQ7NmcwNm40ay8tbjRfLS1fMTZzczQzMjI0YGItNS41YzAzM2E6Yw%3D%3D&signature=163ad24f03c5c2baa2c6c144e74adc3b&tk=tt_webid_v2&vl=&vr=',
 'https://v16-web.tiktok.com/video/tos/useast2a/tos-useast2a-ve-0068c003/c74c06cfbb38484da1ecc181833c1b0b/?a=1988&br=1266&bt=633&cr=0&cs=0&cv=1&dr=0&ds=3&er=&expire=1605137469&l=2020111117301001019018602943028554&lr=tiktok_m&mime_type=video_mp4&policy=2&qs=0&rc=M3N4O3NyZmlkdjMzOTczM0ApMzZmZWQ0ZDw2N2Y2Z2RnNWdhYWEuLWc2aGxfLS0wMTZzc2A1NTMvM2EyLjAxMjReYTU6Yw%3D%3D&signature=8ddef89d8affeace15e12459a0b70b0c&tk=tt_webid_v2&vl=&vr=',
 'https://v16-web.tiktok.com/video/tos/useast2a/tos-useast2a-ve-0068c002/88603e60557348f482e7726e986c5974/?a=1988&br=2768&bt=1384&cr=0&cs=0&cv=1&dr=0&ds=3&er=&expire=1605137420&l=2020111117301001019018602943028554&lr=tiktok_m&mime_type=video_mp4&policy=2&qs=0&rc=anN5a2pnZHQ4czMzOjczM0ApMzs8ZjtnPGVpNzQ8aWdkOmdrLzNobXBmbGhfLS00MTZzczI0Y2M2YWBfXi1eMV9eLzY6Yw%3D%3D&signature=192571046a1daf719a3ef5574c6ebbce&tk=tt_webid_v2&vl=&vr=',
 'https://v16-web.tiktok.com/video/tos/useast2a/tos-useast2a-ve-0068c001/8d056ffafd6b4ad6ad406c9b13e5b14d/?a=1988&br=1752&bt=876&cr=0&cs=0&cv=1&dr=0&ds=3&er=&expire=1605137425&l=2020111117301001019018602943028554&lr=tiktok_m&mime_type=video_mp4&policy=2&qs=0&rc=M3l0NXg2dHJrdzMzODczM0ApaWQ4NjwzZzw4N2gzOzUzM2dfZi5wZl5vMWpfLS0vMTZzc15eXzBfMzMxXy8tMC0tMGA6Yw%3D%3D&signature=117bf14374f361a6650edcd0c7bfae16&tk=tt_webid_v2&vl=&vr=',
 'https://v16-web.tiktok.com/video/tos/useast2a/tos-useast2a-pve-0068/0d01046a478c4f4192394c64804a6a67/?a=1988&br=1916&bt=958&cr=0&cs=0&cv=1&dr=0&ds=3&er=&expire=1605137420&l=2020111117301001019018602943028554&lr=tiktok_m&mime_type=video_mp4&policy=2&qs=0&rc=M3lmeTNzZGZ5czMzNzczM0ApZzQ2NTtkOjs8NzozOThkNmdyX3EtYi40a29fLS1gMTZzczMvLTFeXjVhYGEvYjI0Ll86Yw%3D%3D&signature=cc2179ccd7c6da2973b7a315e7ff9e2d&tk=tt_webid_v2&vl=&vr=',
 'https://v16-web.tiktok.com/video/tos/alisg/tos-alisg-pve-0037c001/80b2305781ed4de5b061e2b60cd2c903/?a=1988&br=3440&bt=1720&cr=0&cs=0&cv=1&dr=0&ds=3&er=&expire=1605137419&l=2020111117301001019018602943028554&lr=tiktok_m&mime_type=video_mp4&policy=2&qs=0&rc=am94bGRzaWhveDMzNjczM0ApOzc5Nmk0M2RmN2dpOzZmOWcvYWZwaGsyL19fLS0zMTRzcy00Mi4tMi5gNDVeYi5eMS06Yw%3D%3D&signature=54558ebaf6f42d446296108ed34ceb9f&tk=tt_webid_v2&vl=&vr=',
 'https://v16-web.tiktok.com/video/tos/useast2a/tos-useast2a-pve-0068/62d6c3ec8f8347589f8ced241163931d/?a=1988&br=2446&bt=1223&cr=0&cs=0&cv=1&dr=0&ds=3&er=&expire=1605137463&l=2020111117301001019018602943028554&lr=tiktok_m&mime_type=video_mp4&policy=2&qs=0&rc=M2V3dDk1bzo6dzMzaDczM0ApN2U2ZjQ7Mzs7NzNnOzhlZWdqcmk2NjFgbTZfLS00MTZzczAvMTBjMjReYTMyLjA2YmA6Yw%3D%3D&signature=25c7b9a6c8486727d4b37bf26d933296&tk=tt_webid_v2&vl=&vr=',
 'https://v16-web.tiktok.com/video/tos/useast2a/tos-useast2a-pve-0068/8335520a8d464e54a8aad17c1a8244c2/?a=1988&br=4836&bt=2418&cr=0&cs=0&cv=1&dr=0&ds=3&er=&expire=1605137431&l=2020111117301001019018602943028554&lr=tiktok_m&mime_type=video_mp4&policy=2&qs=0&rc=Mzp1ajx0bDk7djMzMzczM0ApN2k8M2k3ZWQ6Nzg6ODk8M2dnc2NsLS1jNnJfLS0zMTZzc2FfYjZgLi0tNDBfYS41YWM6Yw%3D%3D&signature=2c2d7870c9adbb1b4d4ffcbcea6e7d19&tk=tt_webid_v2&vl=&vr=',
 'https://v16-web.tiktok.com/video/tos/useast2a/tos-useast2a-ve-0068c002/14005725b9f349819cceef0fe39345d4/?a=1988&br=2352&bt=1176&cr=0&cs=0&cv=1&dr=0&ds=3&er=&expire=1605137449&l=2020111117301001019018602943028554&lr=tiktok_m&mime_type=video_mp4&policy=2&qs=0&rc=M2d2eHdkOGc5eDMzZTczM0ApPGg2Z2ZnZ2Q6NzNpPDpmM2cxcGYtZS1fYTBfLS1fMTZzczUtLWAvMjY2LWAtYTReYF86Yw%3D%3D&signature=25c39dc0a3a36de2e3481debc7e62131&tk=tt_webid_v2&vl=&vr=',
 'https://v16-web.tiktok.com/video/tos/useast2a/tos-useast2a-ve-0068c004/d307128d2b7b407ca69ddb39f4ac9bf0/?a=1988&br=3214&bt=1607&cr=0&cs=0&cv=1&dr=0&ds=3&er=&expire=1605137469&l=2020111117301001019018602943028554&lr=tiktok_m&mime_type=video_mp4&policy=2&qs=0&rc=M2htcnk1cGg0dzMzZjczM0ApaDw1OmRmNGU7N2loOWQ4aWdyaGNgYzNuNmlfLS1iMTZzczYtYGNfMy4tYDU2MDNiMS86Yw%3D%3D&signature=9ba45dfc4d4e4a6d63f200f3238f7eea&tk=tt_webid_v2&vl=&vr=']
```

Comment: класс, спасибо, все работает

Comment: @SpYd3r, [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)